# Azure Machine Learning service (preview) - Minified React Error prevents from viewing experiment

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have not been using Azure Machine Learning service (preview) for too long. To my knowledge it only has been released since the last Microsoft Ignite conference. That's why I think I can not find my question on StackOverflow or any other forum for that matter.

It is as follows:

1. With help of the Azure Machine Learning service SDK in Python I created my experiment in a Jupyter Notebook locally.
2. I then configured it to run a Hyper Drive config,
3. The results came in one by one (as I had a total of 50 runs and 4 simultaneously). It took 7 hours to complete the Hyper Drive run in total.
4. The next day I went to portal.azure.com to view the results and that worked. I was able to see every run of the hyperdrive and could even compare results.

But then....

I have no clue to as what could have happened, but when I tried to navigate to the experiment again I got a blank white screen. When opening the dev console via F12 I got so see a lot of red errors. All from react. I have zero experience with react, but I am quiet sure that this is the error. [React errors when viewing experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVXuM.png)

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this! It's a known issue and a fix is being rolled out.